# Slide menu - move from right to left and back

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin

I have slide menu when I click on screen menu comes out from right to left. How can I write code if I click button to move back from left to right?

My slide menu:

[image]

My code:

```
private void UpdateTableViewPosition(CGPoint positon)
    {
        // set the position of the button based on the provided argument
        _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(positon.X , _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.Y, _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.Width, _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.Height);

        // TODO:
        // if button is outside of the screen
        //     move it back into the screen

        // then move tableview so it is right aligned of the button
        _tableView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(_buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.Right, _tableView.Frame.Y, _tableView.Frame.Width, _tableView.Frame.Height);
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

        UITouch touch = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;

        _moving = false;

        // TODO: fix so that only the button is clickable
        // if the touch clicked the button
        //     open (or close) the view with the following animation code
        UIView.Animate(0.9f, () =>
        {
            // TODO: this animation code is incorrect. Currently it moves the view 100px relatively to the 
            // current position, but it should rather either set the button to the left corner or the right 
            // corner at fixed positions
            UpdateTableViewPosition(new CGPoint(_buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.X - _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.Left, 0));

        }, null);
    }

    public override void TouchesCancelled(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesCancelled(touches, evt);

        _moving = false;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(Foundation.NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

        UITouch touch = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;

        CoreGraphics.CGPoint pos = touch.LocationInView(this);

         if (pos.X > _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.X && pos.X < _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.Right && pos.Y > _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.Y && pos.Y < _buttonToggleVisibility.Frame.Bottom)
        {
            // did click on the view
            _moving = true;
        }

        _buttonToggleVisibility.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
       {

       };
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a public bool to your menu which is set to true when the menu became visible. in your button click method u check if the bool is true and when it is u just use closing animation && logic

Answer (score 0):

I use AutoLayout and UIView animation to move a view of controls up and down. (Think a keyboard but with more flexibility.) The board has a "Done" button, which animatedly moves the board (and it's subviews) out of view.

Since I have an array of boards, there's extra code here addressing the tag property. That's where I find which board to work with.

The key things are to:

- (1) Change the heightAnchor (or in your case the widthAnchor)
- (2) Animate by call the superview's layoutIfNeeded

..

```
private var boardIn:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
private var boardOut:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
private var tabBoards:[TabBoard] = []

public func createControlBoard(
    _ tag:Int
    )  -> ControlBoard {
    let newBoard = ControlBoard(tag)
    boardOut.append(newBoard.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100))
    boardIn.append(newBoard.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0))
    newBoard.doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideTabBoard), for: .touchUpInside)
    tabBoards.append(newBoard)
    return newBoard
}

public func showTabBoard(_ tag:Int) {
    for i in 0...tabBoards.count-1 {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([boardOut[i]])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([boardIn[i]])
        tabBoards[i].makeControlsHidden(true)
    }
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([boardIn[tag-1]])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([boardOut[tag-1]])
    tabBoards[tag-1].makeControlsHidden(false)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded() }
}

public func hideTabBoard(_ tag:Int) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([boardOut[tag-1]])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([boardIn[tag-1]])
    tabBoards[tag-1].makeControlsHidden(true)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```